# Showing that this triangle is a right triangle using vector algebra

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Given this polygon inscribed in a square, I must show that the triangle indicated in blue is right triangle and have side lenghts in proportion $3:4:5$:

[image]

I used the two sides from the left bottom corner as vectors $u$ and $v$ and I'm trying to write the vectors representing the sides of the triangle in terms of $u$ and $v$. Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be these vectors, with $z$ being the (supposed) hypotenuse of the triangle. So

$$z = v + \frac{1}{2}u,$$

but I'm stuck trying to write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. Is this approach correct?

Comment: How can a triangle be a rectangle?

Comment: I believe the intent is to show that the triangle is a right triangle.

Comment: Unclear what the phrase *vector algebra* represents.  Anyway, denote the lower left and upper right Cartesian coordinates as $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$ respectively.  Then all three vertices of the triangle are unambiguously defined.  For example, the vertices of the hypotenuse are $(2,0)$ and $(1,2)$.  So, all that you have to do is compute the coordinates of the *missing* vertex as the intersection of two well defined lines.  Then, you will know the coordinates of all three vertices of the triangle, and therefore can calculate the length of each leg of the triangle.

Comment: Re previous comment, the two pertinent line segments will have endpoints of $[(0,1)--(2,0)]$ and $[(0,0)--(1,2)]$.

Comment: One leg has slope $2$, the other, $-1/2$, so they are perpendicular, so it's a right-angled triangle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson unclear whether your comment  redundant, since *superficially*, you still need to calculate the length of the two legs.  Then, once these legs are calculated, you independently have $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ (et al).

Comment: @user, you don't need to calculate any lengths if all you want to do is to show there's a right angle. You just need to calculate the slope of the line joining $(0,0)$ to $(1,2)$, and the slope of the line joining $(0,1)$ to $(2,0)$, and to see that those two slopes are negative reciprocals of each other. To finish the problem, to show it's a 3-4-5 triangle, for that, yes, more work is needed. But I reckon it's good to check it's a right angle first, so you don't waste any time on a wild goose chase if it isn't.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What I am hinting at is that I am weak at Geometry.  Instead of using my crude method, one might use your method as a starting point.  Then, instead of crudely solving for the coordinates of the 3rd vertex, one might (**somehow**) show that the two legs are in proportion of $(3::4)$.  If this is Geometrically demonstrable, then that coupled with your insight, would represent a Geometric solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

let $\mathbf u = (-1,2), \mathbf v = (-2,1), \mathbf w = (1,2)$

These vectors are the hypotenuse and the extension of the legs of the triangle.

First, the triangle in question is right as the vectors v,w are orthogonal, or $v\cdot w = 0$

We need the projection of $\mathbf u$ onto $\mathbf v: \frac {u\cdot v}{v\cdot v} \mathbf v = \frac {4}{5} \mathbf v$

And the projection of $\mathbf u$ onto $\mathbf w: \frac {u\cdot w}{w\cdot w} \mathbf w = \frac {3}{5} \mathbf w$

And finally the magnitudes of $\bf {u,v, w}$ are all the same.  So, magnitude of these projections and the magnitude of u suggest the required $3:4:5$ ratio.